Getting area between a lens and an ellipse to approximate $\pi$
I have here a desmos graph. You see a tiny bit of space in between the lens and the ellipse, some of which I have approximated using a triangle. Now, I need to calculate the rest of the space between the graphs without actually calculating the area of the lens and the area of the ellipse and then subtracting it. I tried to integrate somehow, by taking the difference of the x values of the ellipse and the circle and took them as rectangles with length $x_c - x_e$ and breadth $dy$, but somehow that didn't work. All of this is an attempt to approximate pi. Check these out for the other questions related to this:
Ques 1
Ques 2
